# How can I populate this data.frame with values for a specific hour?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

So I have two data.frames, one called `yearlywindspeeds`, which should have a value for the wind speed at each hour of the year (8760 hours). The second data.frame contains an average wind speed for each hour of the day (0-23) by month, called `cyprusmonthlywindspeeds`.

I want to be able to populate each [i,j] cell in `yearlywindspeeds` with a value based on what time it is and which month. The first column of `yearlywindspeeds` is an index for the month (`Months`). This is the code I have, which works fine I guess:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(yearlywindspeeds)) {
  if (yearlywindspeeds[i, "Months"] == 1) {
    yearlywindspeeds[i, ] = cyprusmonthlywindspeeds[1, ]
  }
}
```

I could obviously just continue doing this month by month, replacing the rows as I go along, but I just thought that there might be a more elegant/instructional way to do this so that I look up in each cell where I am by row/column and then extract the value from the monthly averages based on a pair of indices i,j.

I would appreciate any help.

To respond to a comment here, these are the column names of the data.frame s

```
> head(yearlywindspeeds)
  Month 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12  13  14  15  16  17  18 19  20  21  22 23
1     1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  3  5  5 5.2 5.2 5.2 5.2 4.2 3.5  3 2.5 2.4 2.2  2
2     1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  3  5  5 5.2 5.2 5.2 5.2 4.2 3.5  3 2.5 2.4 2.2  2
3     1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  3  5  5 5.2 5.2 5.2 5.2 4.2 3.5  3 2.5 2.4 2.2  2
4     1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  3  5  5 5.2 5.2 5.2 5.2 4.2 3.5  3 2.5 2.4 2.2  2
5     1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  3  5  5 5.2 5.2 5.2 5.2 4.2 3.5  3 2.5 2.4 2.2  2
6     1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  3  5  5 5.2 5.2 5.2 5.2 4.2 3.5  3 2.5 2.4 2.2  2

> head(cyprusmonthlywindspeeds)
  Month X0  X1  X2 X3 X4  X5  X6  X7 X8  X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22
1     1  2 2.0 2.0  2  2 2.0 2.0 2.0  2 2.0 3.0   5 5.0 5.2 5.2 5.2 5.2 4.2 3.5 3.0 2.5 2.4 2.2
2     2  2 2.0 2.0  2  2 2.0 2.0 2.0  2 2.0 3.0   4 4.0 4.2 4.2 4.2 5.2 4.2 3.5 3.0 2.5 2.4 2.2
3     3  2 2.0 2.0  2  2 2.0 2.0 2.0  2 2.0 3.0   5 5.0 6.2 6.2 6.2 6.2 5.2 3.5 3.0 2.5 2.4 2.2
4     4  2 2.0 2.0  2  2 2.0 2.0 2.0  2 2.0 3.0   5 5.0 6.2 6.2 6.2 6.2 5.2 3.5 3.0 2.5 2.4 2.2
5     5  3 2.5 2.2  2  2 1.5 1.5 1.8  2 2.5 2.8   3 3.2 3.5 4.2 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 4.5 4.0 4.5
6     6  3 2.5 2.2  2  2 1.5 1.5 1.8  2 2.5 2.8   3 3.2 3.5 4.2 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 4.5 4.0 4.5
  X23
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   2
5   3
6   3
```

Basically, for each of the 24 hours in a day, I have a value for the wind speed based on the month. I want to define a value for the wind speed at each hour of the year. The code I have above actually works--but as I found out, only if the index "Month" is in the same column for both data frames; obviously, the hours have to be arranged in the same order as well--and I went ahead and did it for all 12 months, but I just think there must be a better way to do this.

The present row only takes the values for the wind speed and copies it the requisite number of times, which just seems clunky. There has to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: It would help to have an unambiguous sample of the data from each frame, such as from `dput(head(x))`. (I suspect this can be done without a `for` loop, but input and output formats will dictate.)

Comment: Sounds like a `merge` problem. If you are unwilling to follow the advice to [edit] your question body with a [MCVE], then try to search for examples of the use of `merge`.

Comment: Minor point, Abed, but you'll have a better chance of getting replies (and not have q's closed) if, after you ask the question, you remain around and responsive to comments. From a "strategy" standpoint, after 10-30 minutes your question falls off the "front page" of questions and is much-less-frequently visited. Granted, several people intentionally go back to the older questions, but it is to your advantage to address simple questions while you have our attention. At this point, I'm closing this web page and may not come back to it due to simple interest/inattentiveness. Just FYI! :-)

Comment: Thank you; I try to lurk on here as much as possible but I also wonder if I'm in the right timezone for most people anyway.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work quite easily with a nested for loop if that makes any sense; so, one for loop going through the days, the other checking the months for each day, using indices i and j.